# How to make LED off initially in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, rgb, led

I am working with LED strip. I am new to Arduino. I want the initial value of all LED color to be low. I have used characters as "0, 1, 2, 3" for turning the led on and off for Red, green and blue colors.
[This is the image of RGB LED Strip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5e5j.jpg). [This is the circuit connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhmFb.jpg).

The following is the code:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(BaudRate);

   pinMode(blueLED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(BaudRate);

pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(BaudRate);
}
void loop()
{
 incomingOption = Serial.read();
 switch(incomingOption){
    case '1':
      // Turn ON LED
      digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
      
       
      break;
    case '2':
     
      digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);          
      break;

      case '3':
      // Turn ON LED .. and so on
     
     }
}
```

I want each color to be off initially. How can I do that?

Comment: Why are you calling `Serial.begin(BaudRate);` three times?

Comment: your code contains function calls to turn them on and off so I have no clue why you need to ask this question.

Comment: Are you really using an LED Strip, or a singled RGB LED?  Strips usually require a specific library and commands to control individual LEDs or the whole strip (for example NewPixel).

Comment: @mmixLinus There are non-addressable LED strips.

Comment: Well, nowhere in the code you are turning the Green o Blue Leds ON.  Each case needs to turn on the appropiate LED pin and Off the others. So there are several calls missing in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the `digitalWrite` function.
You should also call `Serial.begin` once.
if your RGB LED strip is **common cathode** the following code is suggested:

```cpp
void setup() {
    pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(blueLED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(blueLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
    Serial.begin(BaudRate);
}

void loop() {
   incomingOption = Serial.read();
   switch(incomingOption){
      case '1':
         // Turn ON LED
         digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH); 
         break;
      case '2':
         digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);          
         break;
      case '3':
         // Turn ON LED .. and so on
      default:
         break;
   }
}
```

**NOTE**
You should use `digitalWrite(pin1, HIGH);` to turn off the line that connected to pin1, if your RGB LED strip is common anode

Comment: It did not work. All the LEDs are High initially. And the color is combined RGB color.

Comment: @SharmaIP   May be your RGB LED strip is common anode. so you should use `digitalWrite(pin1, HIGH);` to turn off the line that connected to pin1.

Comment: What is the component make/model/number of the LED strip?

Comment: My RGB strip is common Anode. digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH); worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use digitalWrite() to the appropriate GPIO and the appropriate gpio state (HIGH/LOW) in your setup() function. This will set your LEDs initially once at startup.
By the way, it is enough to call Serial.begin(BaudRate); only once in your setup() function.